# Why don't Eureka DS Replicas Links work?

Tags: spring-cloud

Why does the DS Replicas not work in the Spring gui? When you click on the links they try to go to http://hostname:8761/eureka/. Shouldn't the link point to http://hostname:8761/?

[image: Eureka GUI]

Answer (score 3):

DS Replicas probably is: "Discovery Service Replicas". In basic configuration which is most often used in all tutorials you have only one eureka server. That field would be filled with other replicas - its recommended to have them to avoid single point of failure :) Its described here:
[Eureka peer awareness](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_peer_awareness)

Comment: Yes. I am aware of this. I have peer awareness already setup and working. I blacked out the replica link before uploading the image. My question is why does the hyperlink point to http://hostname:8761/eureka/. This is the endpoint to register services. I would expect the hyperlink to point the UI of the replica.

Answer (score -1):

By default, the Eureka Service Registry comes with a client behavior too. That means that it will try to register itself in a registry which, by default, is configured to be at http://localhost:8761/eureka. To fix this problem, you can override the property carrying that value (http://localhost:8761/eureka) or set your server port to 8761. However, it's not useful to have the server registering on its own instance (since we're in standalone mode) so we can just disable it. By adding below properties in the application.properties file

```
application.properties

server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```